# OpenCart Pagination not working properly for Specials

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I'm using the default Specials page for OpenCart to display [my Specials](http://www.shanycosmetics.com/specials). I have no idea why the default pagination is not working properly.

If you look at the bottom of the page, it correctly reports that there are 163 specials; however, it only displays 30 products (15 in each page).

The only way I can display the products is by manually typing in `?limit=100` at the end of [my URL](http://www.shanycosmetics.com/specials?limit=100). or hardcode `$data['limit'] = 100;` inside the `getProductSpecials` function of product model.

The pagination looks to be working fine on the category pages.

Has anyone else had issues with this?

Comment: There is something wrong with paginator, probably something is wrongly set in the controller. The `Results per page` field always shows that it is displaying **100 items**, as well as the paginator at the bottom shows **Displaying 100 items of 163** and there are only two pages, though only 15 items are shown... Show us Your controller part that is setting the values for paginator. Did You change the code somehow? Did You install some plugins (e.g. for specials and/or for paginator)?

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension to fix this. Apparently it's a bug in Opencart yet to be fixed.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=14040

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today, if anyone is curious still its fixed in 1.5.6.4. What happened is that the foreach in the controller was using $limit which was defined differently and wonked paginator. That extension above leaves the old one in, and defines another -- this is one of the few times where you should just hard edit your file and not use a vQmod.

Open store/catalog/controller/product/special.php and go near line 229. There is a loop foreach($limits as $limit)...change that whole snippet to match this (using $value instead of $limit). $value will ensure any mods are compatible:

```
foreach($limits as $value){
    $this->data['limits'][] = array(
        'text'  => $value,
        'value' => $value,
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/special', $url . '&limit=' . $value)
    );
}
```